# Cant get the number of days in pandas.. it carries date from another column

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

[image]I have been trying to get number days `(SCN Date - Today)`. I have tried different approaches my latest attempt is as below. It puts date from `SCN Date`  in `Today'

I just need to get number of days in numeric form.

```
import pandas as pd
eod = pd.read_excel('df.xlsx')
import datetime
eod['Today'] =  datetime.date.today()
eod['Today'] = pd.Series(eod['Today'])
eod['Today'] = pd.Series(eod['SCN Date'])
eod['Days'] = eod['Today']-eod['SCN Date']
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Timestamp`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Timestamp.html) with [`Timestamp.floor`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Timestamp.floor.html) for datetimes with no times, extract and convert output timedeltas to days by [`Series.dt.days`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.days.html), solution is without new column:

```
eod = pd.read_excel('df.xlsx')

eod['Days'] = (pd.Timestamp('now').floor('d') - eod['SCN Date']).dt.days
```

Or if necessary convert column to datetimes use [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html):

```
eod['Days'] = (pd.Timestamp('now').floor('d') - pd.to_datetime(eod['SCN Date'])).dt.days
```

Answer (score 0):

First, this is how to get date difference in days with python datetime:

```
date1 = datetime.datetime.now()
date2 = datetime.datetime.now()
delta = date2 - date1
print(delta.days)
```

Then if we apply it to pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
eod = pd.read_excel('Documents/sample.xlsx')
import datetime
eod["Today"] = datetime.datetime.now()
eod["Delta"] = eod["Today"] - eod["SCN Date"]
eod["DeltaDays"] = eod["Delta"].apply(lambda x: x.days)
```

The last line: `eod["DeltaDays"] = eod["Delta"].apply(lambda x: x.days)` means that, for each data in column "Delta", take it's "days" property and save it to column "DeltaDays"

Result:

```
>>> eod
     SCN Date Name                      Today                    Delta  DeltaDays
0  2020-01-01    a 2020-09-10 14:20:30.046694 253 days 14:20:30.046694        253
1  2020-01-02    b 2020-09-10 14:20:30.046694 252 days 14:20:30.046694        252
2  2020-01-03    c 2020-09-10 14:20:30.046694 251 days 14:20:30.046694        251
3  2020-01-04    d 2020-09-10 14:20:30.046694 250 days 14:20:30.046694        250
4  2020-01-05    e 2020-09-10 14:20:30.046694 249 days 14:20:30.046694        249
5  2020-01-06    f 2020-09-10 14:20:30.046694 248 days 14:20:30.046694        248
6  2020-01-07    e 2020-09-10 14:20:30.046694 247 days 14:20:30.046694        247
7  2020-01-08    f 2020-09-10 14:20:30.046694 246 days 14:20:30.046694        246
8  2020-01-09    f 2020-09-10 14:20:30.046694 245 days 14:20:30.046694        245
9  2020-01-10    f 2020-09-10 14:20:30.046694 244 days 14:20:30.046694        244
10 2020-01-11    f 2020-09-10 14:20:30.046694 243 days 14:20:30.046694        243
```